# Eclipse Oxygen Run Java9 Jigsaw Application

Tags: eclipse, java-9, java-platform-module-system

I'm starting learning using new features of java9 Jigsaw.

I follow [this tutorial](https://examples.javacodegeeks.com/core-java/java-9-jigsaw-project-tutorial/) and I manage to create a project with two module and an external module dependency.
(I post the pom files  code below to give an Idea of the product structure)

Now I want to import my maven project in Eclipse Oxygen (with Java9 plugin support) to run and debug the project in Eclipse IDE.

I use Oxygen.1a and I installed Java 9 support for Oxygen 4.7

I use "Import Existing Maven project" and I select the root pom.xml.

Everithing works great I have my project imported two of them are recognized as Java projects (jsaw-date-cli and jigsaw-date-server) and the root module as a simple m2 project.

Now I tried to run jsaw-date-cli Main from eclipse using the common Ran as Java Appliocation" but I revicieved:

```
Error occurred during initialization of boot layer
java.lang.module.FindException: Module jigsaw.date.cli not found
```

How can I configure the project to make the cli project own module available in Run Time?
I Open the build path properties the external modules are correctly imported!

I tried to set also the module in the "RunConfiguration" adding

```
/maven-build/target/modules
```

as `ModulePath` entry but the result is the same.

I tried also to add a VM command-line argument:

```
--module-path  ${workspace_loc:maven-build}/target/modules/
```

But the error is still there.

I can run the project from command line using

```
java -jar --module-path target/modules -m jigsaw.date.cli
```

But I want to run and debug it from eclipse!

Below the poms.xml files:

root pom.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>com.javacodegeeks</groupId>
        <artifactId>jigsaw-date</artifactId>
        <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </parent>
    <artifactId>jigsaw-date-cli</artifactId>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.javacodegeeks</groupId>
                <artifactId>jigsaw-date-service</artifactId>
                <version>${project.version}</version>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.javacodegeeks</groupId>
            <artifactId>jigsaw-date-service</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/../../target/modules</outputDirectory>
                    <archive>
                        <manifest>
                            <mainClass>com.javacodegeeks.jigsaw.date.cli.Main</mainClass>
                        </manifest>
                    </archive>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>copy-dependencies</id>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>copy-dependencies</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/../../target/modules</outputDirectory>
                            <overWriteReleases>false</overWriteReleases>
                            <overWriteSnapshots>false</overWriteSnapshots>
                            <overWriteIfNewer>true</overWriteIfNewer>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

jigsaw-cli pom.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>com.javacodegeeks</groupId>
        <artifactId>jigsaw-date</artifactId>
        <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </parent>
    <artifactId>jigsaw-date-service</artifactId>

    <properties>
        <org.apache.commons.lang.version>3.4-module</org.apache.commons.lang.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
                <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
                <version>${org.apache.commons.lang.version}</version>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/../../target/modules</outputDirectory>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>copy-dependencies</id>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>copy-dependencies</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/../../target/modules</outputDirectory>
                            <overWriteReleases>false</overWriteReleases>
                            <overWriteSnapshots>false</overWriteSnapshots>
                            <overWriteIfNewer>true</overWriteIfNewer>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

jigsaw-service pom.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>com.javacodegeeks</groupId>
        <artifactId>jigsaw-date</artifactId>
        <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </parent>
    <artifactId>jigsaw-date-service</artifactId>

    <properties>
        <org.apache.commons.lang.version>3.4-module</org.apache.commons.lang.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
                <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
                <version>${org.apache.commons.lang.version}</version>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/../../target/modules</outputDirectory>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>copy-dependencies</id>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>copy-dependencies</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/../../target/modules</outputDirectory>
                            <overWriteReleases>false</overWriteReleases>
                            <overWriteSnapshots>false</overWriteSnapshots>
                            <overWriteIfNewer>true</overWriteIfNewer>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Comment: In your run configuration, is the classpath or modulepath used?

Comment: I added also this information

Comment: Do you use Oxygen.1a? Make also sure, you have uninstalled the Java 9 BETA plug-in for Oxygen (see [Eclipse bug 526065](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=526065)).

Comment: I use Oxygen.1a and I installed `Java 9 support for Oxygen 4.7`

Comment: Oxygen.1a contains Java 9 support. [Due to a bug you have to uninstall the _Java 9 support for Oxygen (4.7)_ plug-in manually](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=526065).

Answer (score 0):

I finally manage to run the project using eclipse and also using the debugger, without remove or add any plugin.

I just add ad `VM argument` in the run configuration:

```
--module-path  ${workspace_loc:maven-build}/target/modules/ -m jigsaw.date.cli/com.javacodegeeks.jigsaw.date.cli.Main
```